# How to insert variable in fswatch regex?

Tags: fswatch

I'm trying to use a variable to identify `mxf` or `mov` file extensions.  The following works where I explicitly name the file extensions with a regular expression.

```
${FSWATCH_PATH} -0 \
-e ".*" --include ".*\.[ mxf|mov ]" \
--event Updated --event Renamed --event MovedTo -l $LATENCY \
$LOCAL_WATCHFOLDER_PATH \
| while read -d "" event
  do
<code here>
done
```

How can I use a variable for the file extensions, where the variable name is `FileTriggerExtensions`? The code below doesn't work:

```
FileTriggerExtensions=mov|mxf

${FSWATCH_PATH} -0 \
-e ".*" --include ".*\.[ $FileTriggerExtensions ]" \
--event Updated --event Renamed --event MovedTo -l $LATENCY \
$LOCAL_WATCHFOLDER_PATH \
| while read -d "" event
  do
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use Bash or a similar shell?

```
FileTriggerExtensions=mov|mxf
-bash: mxf: command not found
```

Use quotes or escape the pipe symbol.